# Can't add an existing directory to QT Creator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Im trying to open some files in QT Creator, The file names are `"VertexShader.vert"` and `"FragmentShader.frag"` both files are in my projects directory, But When I try to open Them I have to do something like this: `open("/home/ali/QT projects/OpenGL/VertexShader.vert")` (I have to pass the full path). I added these files to my directory but nothing happened.

[image]

As you can see both `.frag` and `.vert` are in my directory but I still have to write the full path name in order to open these files. Here is my `.pro` file:

```
QT    += core gui opengl

QT += core
QT -= gui

TARGET = OpenGL
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp \
    GlWindow.cpp \
    shadercode.cpp


HEADERS += \
    GlWindow.h

LIBS += -L/home/GLEW/lib -lGLEW -lGLU -lGL

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../GLEW/lib/release/ -lGLEW
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../GLEW/lib/debug/ -lGLEW
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../GLEW/lib/ -lGLEW

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../GLEW/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../GLEW/include

DISTFILES += \
    VertexShader.vert \
    FragmentShader.frag
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably confusing your *project source directory* with the *working directory* of your program being run.

Note that when your project resides in, e.g. "/home/ali/QT projects/OpenGL/", this is *usually not* the working directory when you run your program. The working directory is probably something in the *parent folder*, depending on your build configuration. You can adjust that in the project options page.

[image]